# How to revert object state to initial?

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
export class ObjectLayer {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}
```

I get this from server and set to `currentVersion`:

```
public currentVersion: ObjectLayer;

setVersion(object: ObjectLayer) {
   this.currentVersion = object;
}
```

Then user can change `currentVersion` version. How to revert version to initial version at any time?

Comment: Make a copy of the initial object. Then restore that copy.

Comment: Where if method `setVersion` changes versions, I need to clone only first object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the initial state.

```
private _oldVersion?: ObjectLayer;
public currentVersion: ObjectLayer;

setVersion(object: ObjectLayer) {
   this._oldVersion = this.currentVersion;
   this.currentVersion = object;
}

restoreVersion() {
    if (!this._oldVersion) throw new Error('Nothing to restore');
    this.currentVersion = this._oldVersion;
    this._oldVersion = undefined;
}
```